# git status pause listing on terminal

Tags: windows, git

When I'm doing a `git status` on my Git Bash, due to a massive untracked and added files, the terminal is like scrolling the list up to the end of the file. Is there a way I can pause it so I can view all files one by one? Similar to how `dir /p` works.

Comment: I think its not possible to me since I use Git on windows, I guess? Because if I do that, it will return `sh: more: command not found`

Answer (score 3):

The most portable way would be to redirect the output of the `git status` command to a file `output_file`:

```
git status > output_file
```

If you do not specify any path this newly created file will be created in the current directory and will be shown as untracked. Use:

```
git status > C:\Users\user\output_file
```

To redirect the output to any location.

Comment: On windows how do the path look like?

Comment: Nothing happened. No file, no output messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pause it and view them one by one (that I know of). You may however be interested in using `git status --short` which puts each file on a single line, and might make it a little easier for you to decipher.

Comment: Still it overcomes the scroll on my terminal. I can't see some of the files above my scroll limit.

Comment: You may want to look into Gitx @ http://gitx.frim.nl once you install that you can run `gitx` and view the stage where you should be able to view your files more easily. Edit: That product is for Mac only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you work under the bash environment?You can do this like you are in terminal:
git status | tee status 
(note: it'll echo the "git status"'s output to the "status" file)